# Set flutter textfield inside Listview and get the value of each textfield on submit

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

controller:

```
List<TextEditingController> areaController = [];
```

Code:

```
Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            areaController.add(TextEditingController());
            return TextField(
              controller: areaController[index],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (text) {},
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Area",
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Submit'),
          onPressed: () {
            //get the value of every index textfield
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

How can I set flutter `textfield` inside `Listview` and get the value of each `textfield` on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a `for`-loop? just call `.text` on each `TextField` to get the text value.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Submit'),
              onPressed: () {
                for (int i = 0; i < areaController.length; i++) {
                  print(areaController[i].text);
                }
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found other way as well using [**.map()**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method

```
 ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Submit'),
      onPressed: () {
        var fieldsValue = areaController.map((value) => value.text);
        print(fieldsValue);
      },
    )
```